# How do you combine custom font-face with bootstrap's glyphicons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-face, glyphicons

I did something like this

```
@font-face{
  font-family:"MYFONT" !important;
  src: url("/assets/MYFONT.otf") format("opentype") !important;
}
```

And then I added

```
*{
  font-family:"MYFONT", sans !important;
}
```

It obliterated the glyphicons from Bootstrap.

How do I globally declare my font and yet keep the bootstrap glyphicon from being destroyed throughout my site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `*`, because it sets the font-family for all elements.

The quick fix is to do it like this: `body { font-family:"MYFONT", sans; }`

The correct fix is to use the LESS/SASS version of bootstrap and change the variable `@font-family-sans-serif` to use your custom font.